# Touch Event for images and sprites in Starling

Tags: image, events, touch, listener, starling-framework

i have a class it is name "Tiles". And also i have a class it is name "TilesManager" for manage to Tiles. in TilesManager 25 Tiles generating from Pool.

How can Listen each Tiles for Touch Event? I need to learn row and line info of touched Tiles?

```
        for(var i:int=0; i<25; i++)
        {
        row = i % 5;
        line = Math.floor(i / 5);
        var b:Tiles = pool.getSprite() as Tiles;
        b.x = 20 + row * 100;
        b.y = 20 + line * 100;

        b.row = row;
        b.line=line;

        tiles.push(b);
        play.addChild(b);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

// Just make sure you import Starling Event not the Flash one
// The event will carry the current triggered target and its data (tile)

```
b.addEventLister(Event.TRIGGERED, onTileTriggered);
```

Comment: Event.TRIGGERED is only for buttons